# Is it possible to use AWS Cognito to manage profiles with multiple roles?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have an application that needs to have full control over the elements that will be displayed on the user's screen according to their profile. For example, the admin can see all the menus in the application and the "client" will only see the menus that make sense to him. In addition, on this screen that the customer can see he will not be able to see the "delete" button, only ADMINS and other profiles such as managers and etc.

Currently, I have a very simple structure that makes this control, I use the following tables:

- User
- Profile
- Roles
- Profile_Roles

NOTE: I can have thousands of "roles" and dozens of "Profiles".

This structure, which is basic, solves my problem, but I wouldn't want to keep this type of application. because in the future I will have change password, MFA and etc and this is out of my business.

Reading the Cognito documentation, I know that it can deliver a lot of these features I need, but I couldn't be sure if it delivers the "profile vs roles" feature. Reading the documentation (more than once) I still couldn't figure out how to create the roles and "bind them" to the profile. Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to create profiles in Cognito?
2. If yes, is there any limit to the profile number?
3. Is it possible to create "roles" in Cognito and tie them to each profile?
4. If yes, is there any limit to the number of roles created?
5. Is there any surprise "cost" when using cognito or is it just the 50k active users per month?
6. If cognito does not deliver this, is there any other SaaS be it from google, microsoft or another that delivers this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Not really, there is [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html) that shows that the limits are tied to how much users are accessing the service, nothing about limit of users.
   But 50k should be doable with Cognito
3. Yes. A profile can even have multiple roles
4. I havent found something about this
5. I also dont know
6. I dont know about SaaS that can do this as well, but you dont have a backend? This is not something difficult to maintain in the backend